# How do I get a specific value from 2 dimensional object array [PHP]

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a array, called $args and on entry ['question'], another array is inserted via a function called "retrieveQuestion($subtopicId);"

I want to retrieve a value from the retrieveQuestion array, while it is in the $args array.
I would assume that would be something like this:
$questionId = $args[questionId]['question'];
With questionId the value that I want to extract.

var_dump($args) returns:

```
array(2) {
["question"]=>
array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(SchoolX\Models\Exercise)#16 (6) {
      ["subtopid_QuestionId":"SchoolX\Models\Exercise":private]=>
      int(1)
      ["subtopicId":"SchoolX\Models\Exercise":private]=>
      int(1)
      ["questionId":"SchoolX\Models\Exercise":private]=>
      int(1)
      ["title":"SchoolX\Models\Exercise":private]=>
      string(21) "Tel dit bij elkaar op"
      ["description":"SchoolX\Models\Exercise":private]=>
      string(3) "1+1"
      ["type":"SchoolX\Models\Exercise":private]=>
      int(1)
   }
}
```

So to sum it up, I want to get the value "questionId" (shown in this var_dump($args)) to be assigned to another variable called $questionId. But I don't know how to do that.

All help or advice is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That structure is an array with a single element with key "question". That element holds an array with a single element with key 0. That element again holds an object with various properties.

Comment: So properties in that object can be accessed with `$args['question'][0][<key-of-property>]`, where `<key-of-property>` has to be replaced by the required key, obviously. I do not see how you can find out some ID from the given structure. You have to know what you want.

Comment: I would suggest using php classes for this kind of structure. http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=class&scope=quickref

Comment: `$args['question'][0]` is an object, not an array. It's an object of class `Schoolx/Models/Exercise`. All the properties are private, so you need to use class methods to access it.

Comment: Check the class definition, see if it has a method like `getQuestionId()` to do what you need.